# htaccess rules not working everytime, sometimes 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Okay so this is a bit odd, my htaccess rules don't seem to work every time. Sometime it sends people to a 404 page. But if they try the same link again, it then works.

Here my my rules:

```
  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/page\=([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1&page=$3 [N,NC,QSA]
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with those rules? It basically turns index.php?module=articles_full&aid=123&title=title to /articles/title.123

I also have this to redirect old links to the new ones, don't know if anyone knows if they somehow conflict sometimes?

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} threads/(.*)\.([0-9]+)/*

  RewriteRule index.php /articles/%1\.%2?from=oldSite [R=301,L]
```

A link to my full htaccess: http://pastebin.com/G0AxxiHb

Looking through error logs for today (30th) these jump out at me:

```
[Wed Jan 30 09:44:30 2013] [error] [client 2.229.9.52] File does not exist: /home/gamingon/public_html/articles, referer: http://plus.url.google.com/url?sa=z&n=1359539066078&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamingonlinux.com%2Farticles%2Frolling-survival-a-new-alpha-funded-game-on-desura.1681&usg=V4xV32LxoWJ1cPOvrD_XZgftgN8.
```

That one looks like a link i posted on G+, i'm guessing because it has added "&usg=V4xV32LxoWJ1cPOvrD_XZgftgN8" to the end of the url?

```
[Wed Jan 30 11:34:43 2013] [error] [client 100.43.83.149] File does not exist: /home/gamingon/public_html/$10,000 to finish on Kickstarter
```

That seems to miss "/articles/", the id and it has spaces in the name? Not sure how that happened maybe someone manually typed it?

Seems to be a few of these too:

```
[Wed Jan 30 06:32:38 2013] [error] [client 94.246.88.189] File does not exist: /home/gamingon/public_html/articles
```

Do you think maybe i need to have something added to the two /articles/ rules to check for links that get stuff added onto the end? Like links from twitter, g+ etc?

Comment: Try and find those 404 requests in both error.log and access.log, and pastebin the relevant lines, as well.

Comment: @LiamDawe did you got any solution for this. I am facing the same issue